# Camera's preview corrupted on Nexus 5 with Android 6

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

We got a big camera application which supports camera2 interface. It works fine on Android 5.1 and other versions. But after Nexus 5 was upgraded to Android 6 we've got critical issue.
Camera's preview is half-visible! No errors in Logcat. Even more, capturing of still image is works fine, even preview frames is good, only visible preview on SurfaceView is kind of clipped.
Only one thing is helping - restarting by 'home' button. After this action if we run application we can see entire preview. Closing application by 'back' button will broke again preview.

[image: clipped preview on Android 6]

Comment: a testcase for this would help - I'm lazy, not really feeling like writing one myself ;)

Comment: it's hard to post some example code, coz application is very big, camera management code is big too and I don't know exactly which part of code is causing this problem (((

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Android M:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191251

It'll be fixed in an upcoming update.  Until then, possible workarounds:

1. Always create a new surface view when attaching to a camera device
2. Force the surface to reconfigure by setting the surface view holder to (0,0) or (1,1) and THEN setting it to the desired width and height after OnSurfaceChanged
3. Do not pass the surface itself to the camera framework until after B, and after the second OnSurfaceChanged callback is fired.
4. If the app does not lock the orientation to portrait / landscape then repeat step B when the activity orientation configuration changes.

Comment: Thanks, Eddy! I already post a comment to that solution in code.google page and let me dublicate it here:

I'm trying to implement 2)
According to logcat I did it right like you suggest:
1) Reconfigured surfaceView size to (1,1) at start of application
2) After onSurfaceChanged call I started logic to configure desired size of surfaceView.
3) After next onSurfaceChanged call I pass surfaceView as target to configure preview request of CameraCaptureSession.

Result: sometimes preview is still corruped.